# Increase border size using content aware fill within batch processing in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing, fill, borders

I would like to increase the border width of a yellow image border and perform this action within a batch process for multiple similar images within Photoshop.

So far I performed the following steps and tried to save them as "actions" to allow their use in batch processing:

- increase canvas size around the image with the thin yellow border
- select the white area (created by the increased canvas size) around the image using the magic wand tool
- perform content aware fill. This step is performed to ensure best results, as the yellow colour of the thin border around the images is not completely homogenous and the yellow tone also varies slightly between images. As sampling area I chose "custom" and selected the yellow border using the sampling brush tool.

The problem is, that the last step fails within batch processing multiple similar images. I think the reason is that the "custom" selected sampling area can't be applied in a batch process.

I would appreciate any advice on how to automate this action. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using "content aware". Maybe I'm missing something. It's not working as you are expecting because the "content" you have selected, based on the steps described, is white. So it's using the white content to fill the area, well, white.

Assuming it's a 1 layer, flat, no transparency, "Background layer" image

1. Set the background color to the yellow
2. Increase canvas size
3. Done

For a "flat" image, whatever color the background color is set to will be the color of the additional canvas area when you increase the canvas size by default. (There are options to change this as shown in the animation above.)

---

Based on comments regarding some slight variations in the existing yellow border, I would....

- Set the background color to the yellow.
- Select All
- `Select > Modify > Contract`
- 20px (or whatever you feel is correct), and tick `Apply effect at canvas bounds`
- `Select > inverse`
- `Edit > Fill` - Background Color, normal, 100%
- `Image > Canvas Size` - enter values and hit `OK`

[image]

There's no "magic wand" here, nothing which requires a "user click". It can all be automated easily. This does assume all the cards have relatively the same 20px border - or if they don't - a slight 1-2px edge around the inner artwork, where the yellow may not *exactly* match, isn't really a problem.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I thought about simply using yellow as canvas background colour. Unfortunately, the yellow border is not uniform in its colour. So if I choose a single yellow colour as canvas background, the transition might be perfect at the top, but not at the sides and bottom. In addition, the yellow border colour varies between images I want to batch-process. So in addition to variations within the images, there are variations of the yellow colour between images. For this reason I chose content aware, as this procedure can adapt to local changes in the yellow colour.

Comment: @JoBrick Okay.. then I believe you need at least part of the yellow contained within the selection you make. Content Aware is going to be restricted to the *selection* if there's no yellow in the selection, it won't see it. Perhaps expand/contract the selection a bit after making it. Or, use the `Border` option if you know the pixels width you need.

Comment: If I only process a single image, the content-aware filling works. I select the white empty area as area which is supposed to be filled. Afterwards, Photoshop asks me to select the "reference area" called "custom sampling area" using the "sampling brush tool". I indicated the selected sampling area in pink. This is basically what teaches the algorithm how to fill the white empty area in a "content-aware" manner. If I do this only for 1 image, it works and the result is what I designated as "expected result". If I perform this in batch automation, then the last filling step fails.

Comment: I just saw your new comment. I will try to include some yellow into my selection! This is a good idea! I will report back how it works!

Comment: Perhaps you need the user interaction step for that part of the action (if you don't have it set already). But that means you'll need to do that for batch image, making the "batch" less useful.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am afraid of, that it would require a user interaction step. I'll try including some of the yellow in my selection, however, as you suggested. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate your input!

Comment: Any variations in the yellow border are most *probably* due to jpg artifacts or issues related to the card being scanned/photographed. It's highly doubtful the cards were actually printed with any intentional variation in the border. I'd be inclined to select the yellow border and fill it with a solid yellow, then expand the canvas -- but that's just my take. I don't know your full project desires.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I think the variations are definitely JPG artefacts and/or caused by scanning. I think that's a great approach to select the yellow border using the magic wand tool and then fill it with a solid yellow. And then I can use your initial approach using that yellow as background colour for the extended canvas!! Perfect solution! Thanks!

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct answer, but as I am a new member it doesn't let me upvote!

Comment: Not a problem @JoBrick -- I'm aware of new user limitations `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good answer from @Scott which shows what is probably the sane thing to do. But I'll try to show how you *could* automatize using *Content-Aware Fill* to expand a border around an image. In this case, it's probably not needed, but you could be dealing with images which actually had some texture worth preserving in the border.

I know from your other question about Pokémon cards what your end goal is, so I'll put in a few extra steps that will help you create an image which not only has an extended border, but also has the right physical dimensions (63×88 mm).

First you have to manually select the border. In your particular case it seems to work using *Magic Wand* tool with *Sample Size* set to *3 by 3 Average" and *Tolerance* set to *20* (*Anti-alias* and *Contiguous* ticked on).

With other kinds of images (like drawings) you might have to use *Rectangular Marquee Tool*, *Quick Selection Tool* or perhaps even *Object Selection Tool* or *Select > Subject*.

We'll assume you that your images are *flattened* and that you've clicked the yellow border with *Magic Wand* with the mentioned settings. Then you can start recording an action in the *Actions* panel. (It's a long recipe, so I won't go into every detail.)

1. **Convert the *Background Layer* to a *Smart Object*.**
   This is done to protect the image from getting cropped.
2. **Perform *Select > Inverse*.**
3. **Perform *Select > Modify > Contract* and contract by *4 px*.**
   This is done to make sure you don't have any stray pixels selected. Won't work if they have a radius larger than 4 px.
4. **Perform *Select > Modify > Expand* and expand by *3 px*.**
   This is done to get back to the same "bounding box" as before, but 1 px smaller to crop it a tiny bit tighter.
5. **Perform *Image > Crop*.**
6. **Enter *Image > Image Size*. Untick *Resample*. Input the physical width of the printed rectangle in the *Width* field. Press *OK*.**
   I'm *guessing* the width could be 57 mm, but you should try to check that. This is done to automatically adjust the *resolution* of the image so the image "knows" its own size. Later you can then scale the image simply by entering the wanted resolution as you know once and for all that the dimensions are correct. Or rather as correct as possible with these low res scans.
7. **Make a *Layer Mask* on the layer with the current selection.**
   This is done to save the selection for later use.
8. **Enter *Image > Canvas Size*. Make sure *Relative* is unticked. *Anchor* is in the center. In the *Width* and *Height* fields, input the correct physical size *including bleed*.**
   Pokémon cards should be 63×88 mm, so with 3 mm bleed you get 69×94 mm.
9. **Duplicate the layer.**
10. **Select the *Layer Mask* of the duplicate layer.**
11. **Invert the *Layer Mask* of the duplicate layer using <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.**
12. **Rasterize the duplicate layer.**
13. **Select the *Layer Mask* of the duplicate.**
14. **Apply the *Layer Mask* of the duplicate layer.**
    This deletes everything from the layer, but the border, making it easy to fill it with *Content-Aware Fill* without any pollution from the rest of the image.
15. **Select the opacity of the duplicate layer by <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd>-clicking its thumbnail.**
16. **Perform *Select > Inverse*.**
17. **Perform *Select > Modify > Expand* and expand by *2 px*.**
    This is done to in case there is a 1-2 px border on the border.
18. **Perform *Edit > Content-Aware Fill*. Use the default settings and set *Output To* to *Current Layer*.**
19. **Move the duplicate layer below the original layer.**
20. **Select the *Layer Mask* of the original layer.**
21. **Delete the *Layer Mask* of the original layer.**
22. **Perform *Layer > Flatten Image*.**
23. **Perform *Select > Deselect*.**

Phew, that was many steps, sorry. Perhaps it could be simplified a bit and perhaps you would want to tweak some of the values, but this is the main idea.

This is how it looks in action:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very elaborate answer. This is indeed amazing! For my project, it is probably sufficient to replace the complete border and fill it with one selected yellow colour. But your approach is highly relevant if there is a similar problem where the texture in the border needs to be maintained. It looks complicated at first, but following the steps one by one it is quite easy to do, and it's amazing that this procedure can be automated. I am also highly amazed by these gifs illustrating the workflow.

Comment: Yesterday, I already accepted the answer of Scott. It is a shame I can't accept two answers. And as I am a new member, I can't upvote your post. But I would like to express my gratitude for working out and sharing this solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome.  I was eager to show this solution. Don't worry about the upvote. Not everything can be done in 3 steps. So this took 23 steps, but many things we do take many steps. We just don't normally write them down. It can be reused, so I think it's worth it. I also wanted to show you how it's easy to get the scale right by simply cropping to a known width and entering the dimensions. (Btw: The gif is made with [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/)).